# Python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'elftools.common.py3compat'

Tags: python, pwntools

PC: windows 11
wsl 2, ubuntu-22.04

I was gonna install 'pwntools' by following these instructions

```
apt-get update
apt-get install python3 python3-pip python3-dev git libssl-dev libffi-dev build-essential
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pwntools
```

after installing i tested it.
And this happened.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/kimminjun514/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pwn/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pwn.toplevel import *
  File "/home/kimminjun514/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pwn/toplevel.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pwnlib import *
  File "/home/kimminjun514/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pwnlib/dynelf.py", line 57, in <module>
    from pwnlib import elf
  File "/home/kimminjun514/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pwnlib/elf/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pwnlib.elf.corefile import Core
  File "/home/kimminjun514/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pwnlib/elf/corefile.py", line 79, in <module>
    from elftools.common.py3compat import bytes2str
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'elftools.common.py3compat'
```

What's going on with my computer?
Do I have to buy a new computer?

I've tried a lot of things.
I deleted WSL and reinstalled it.
But that didn't work.

I've googled thousand of times but i'm still stuck with this problem.

Comment: [Seems to be a known issue](https://github.com/Gallopsled/pwntools/issues/2260). I found that by searching for "py3compat" in the repo. I have no experience with this library myself, but the error makes it seem like a bug: dependency issue at runtime instead of at install-time. And just to be clear, there's no earthly reason you'd need to buy a new computer to fix an issue with a Python library.

Comment: BTW, welcome back to Stack Overflow! Check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) for tips.

Answer (score 6):

Check whether the version of `pyelftools` is `0.30`, after the test, the version of `0.29` will not report errors, so choose to uninstall the current version and replace the old version

```
pip uninstall pyelftools -y
pip install pyelftools==0.29
```

I hope you found this useful!

Comment: This command, when I copied and pasted it, uninstalled pip! ```Found existing installation: pyelftools 0.30
Uninstalling pyelftools-0.30:
  Successfully uninstalled pyelftools-0.30
Found existing installation: pip 21.3.1
Uninstalling pip-21.3.1:
  Successfully uninstalled pip-21.3.1```

Comment: Downgrading to 0.29 helped.